# Paying Schengen visa for a friend

Tags: schengen, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-accommodation, visa-sponsors

I'm a US citizen planning a one-week trip to Europe in a couple of months. Per my citizenship I can enter visa-free for 90 days.

I want to invite an old friend along, who is a citizen of the Philippines (and a current resident of Dubai). I will pay for all her expenses: airfare, train fare, hotel fare, insurance, food, and entry to touristy places.

She is going through the Schengen visa application process. The question I have is how to answer #33: "Cost of travelling and living during the applicant’s stay is covered". This question has both of us a little bit baffled on how to answer.

I can put airfare and the train ticket in her name, but hotels are prepaid in my name, not hers. And as I don't live in the EU, we can't put anything about "Surname and first name of the inviting person(s) in the Member State(s)" or "Name and address of inviting company/organisation".

I want to make sure we do this right. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you going to enter the country separately? I suspect this is not going to be an easy one...

Comment: @jcaron why won't it be easy?

Comment: If I put myself in the shoes of the consular officer or IO, I see someone from a country that is not very high on their preference list, coming in with the cost of her stay in the Schengen area covered by someone who I don't even know if they are actually coming... Maybe I'm negative, but I don't see that as a stroll in the park...

Comment: The plan is to meet in Amsterdam on the same day, arriving separately.  We stay together until the last day, when we both go home separately from Rome.

I hear you, jcaron, but I really hope you're wrong.  Anything you can suggest to improve matters?

Comment: Bill was the visa approved? Either way any additional details you can share to help future applicants?

Comment: @Davez2000 sorry for the very late reply but yes it was.  It was approved about a week too late and we lost a LOT of money on prearranged tickets.

Answer (score 3):

For question 33, *Cost of travelling and living during the applicant’s stay is covered,* check *by a sponsor* and *other (please specify).*  Write your name next to the latter check box.

Under *means of support,* either check *accommodation provided* and *prepaid transport* or check *all expenses covered,* as you see fit.  If you want to add something else, you can also check *other (please specify)* and add it.

For 31, which in this case is asking for *name of hotel(s) or temporary accommodation(s) in the member state(s),* the fact that the hotel reservations are in your name is not particularly important, but you should probably mention it to avoid confusion.  The answer would therefore look something like

> Hotel Foo, Somethingstraße 21, Berlin
>   Hôtel Bar, 22 Rue Something, Paris
>   (all reserved by Bill Mill)

For 32, *name and address of inviting company/organization,* leave it blank or write "not applicable."